# Unit Testing - How should I test this kind of design?

Tags: unit-testing

In my application there are 2 layers in our design: APIs and Operations.

1.**Operations** implement the "real" logic of code, for example: Authenticating the user, Retrieving book information, Informing a user that his book has been viewed.

The same operation may be used by many APIs.

2.**APIs** are executed by users: they receive parameters, and then execute various operations according to the logic of the API.

For example: ViewBookAPI:

```
class BookApis
{
/**
    * authenticateUserOperation, retreiveBookOperation, informUserBookViewOperation
    * are injected to this class. (Dependency Injection)
*/  
public function viewBookApi($bookId, $accessToken)
{
    $internalUserId = $this->authenticateUserOperation($accessToken);

    $book = $this->retrieveBookOperation($bookId, $internalUserId);

    $this->informUserBookWasViewedOperation($book->getOwnerUserId(), $bookId);

        return $book->getContent();
    }
}
```

---

How should I test this design?

1.If I test the APIs, then I'll have to repeat the same tests for APIs which are using the same operations.

2.If I test the operations, all I have to do is to verify that an API is using the operations correctly.

But what if a wrong object is injected to an API? No test would fail then.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your design is quite common (and rightfully so), so I'm a bit surprised that this question keeps coming up.

There are two types of tests you need here:

1. **Integration tests** - make sure that the flow that starts with the API call and ends with the Operations layer doing its job, is working correctly
2. **Unit tests** - test each of the classes of the API layer, as well as of the Operations layer

Integration tests are pretty self explanatory (if not, let me know and I'll elaborate), so I'm guessing that you're referring to unit tests. The two different layers need to be tested differently.

**The Operations layer:**

Here you're trying to check that the classes doing the actual job are working. This means that you should instantiate the class you're testing, feed it with input, and check that the output it provides matches your expectations.

Say you have a class of this sort:

```
public class OperationA {
    public int multiply(int x, int y) {
        return x * y;
    }
}
```

Checking that it does what you expect would mean writing a test such as (the test cases themselves are just an example, do not take too seriously):

```
public class OperationATest {
    @Test
    public void testMultiplyZeroByAnyNumberResultsInZero() {
        OperationA op = new OperationA();

        assertEquals(0, op.multiply(0, 0));
        assertEquals(0, op.multiply(10, 0));
        assertEquals(0, op.multiply(-10, 0));
        ...
    }

    @Test
    public void testMultiplyNegativeByNegativeResultsInPositive() {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

**The API layer:**

Here you're trying to check that the classes are using the right classes from the Operations layer, in the right order, doing the right operations. In order to do that, you should use mocks, and use the `verify` operations of mocks.

Say you have a class of this sort:

```
public class API_A {

    private OperationA op;

    public API_A(OperationA op) {
        this.op = op;
    }

    public int multiplyTwice(int a, int b, int c) {
        int x = op.multiply(a, b);
        int y = op.multiply(x, c);

        return y;
    }
}
```

Checking that it does what you expect would mean (using Mockito syntax) writing a test such as:

```
public class API_A_Test {
    @Test
    public void testMultiplyTwiceMultipliesTheFirstNumberByTheSecondAndThenByTheThird() {
        OperationA op = mock(OperationA.class); 
        when(op.multiply(12, -5)).thenReturn(60);
        API_A api = new API_A(op);

        api.multiply(12, -5, 0);

        verify(op).multiply(12, -5);
        verify(op).multiply(-60, 0);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I sense a contradiction here. 
It seems you have

- Operations = reusable blocks of logic
- APIs = delegate to operations + script of which operations to call

From that, I'd say you'd need to test both since
* An operation itself maybe implemented correctly. Just having API tests may fail multiple clients/tests for a single bug
* An API might not be calling a required (and implemented) operation... even though the operation tests may pass.

So:

1. Tests for operations - validate the reusable blocks
2. Tests for APIs - verify logic internal to the APIs + check whether the right operations were invoked (can use mocks).You **don't** duplicate/test the logic inside the operations here.
3. I don't usually test dependency injection - because it's unlikely that someone fakes a collaborator. (Unless it's a penetration tester). You could write a test for that as well though.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, it seems like you need two layers of tests.

First, you need to test the basic building blocks - the operations. E.g., you should test `authenticateUserOperation` with a valid token, with an invalid token and with a `NULL`.

Once you've tested all the operations, you can move on to test the logic of the APIs. The idea here is not to double the testing code, but to test **only** the business logic. This can be achieved by  [mocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) or [injecting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) operations with known behaviors, and checking how the APIs deal with them.
For example, you could create a mock `authenticateUserOperation` which always fails and test that `viewBookApi` returns `NULL` (or throws an exception) when its used. This way you only test how the API handles the results of the operations without duplicating the tests.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your first  question, there is no way you can cover this by only unit tests (like you 'tagged' it). Also maybe you must consider the usage of [Pairwise testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-pairs_testing) for your test logic creation. This will support the dependency on *interactions between the Operations & APIs*.

Relating to *wrong object is injected to an API*, after [DI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) is involved, this makes your unit testing a bit easier. Since the components are *loosely coupled*, you can use a dummy mock class to act like a component needed. And by doing so - your code will be very flexible. Maybe this diagram will help you:

[image]

But I don't think this is the only case that you are looking for. So I can propose you to include in your test code the [Decorator design pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/decorator-design-pattern) and by it's concept attach additional responsibilities to the test object dynamically for the API-Operations relation.

Answer (score 1):

You should perform two set of test here. Unit test and integration test

1) **Unit tests** - this set of test should be written for each Operations methods to make sure that particular method is working as expected. Now methods can have different path (if else /exception). You should write multiple unit tests to verify each of this path. Since its a unit test you should mock all the external calls(call's happening to other classes) which will make sure all the things you have done in that function is behaving correctly. Since you don't have any logic in api classes no need to write unit tests for them

2)  **Integrations Tests** - write integration tests to make actual api calls. These tests will verify your end to end scenario (api, operation).

If you have any persistence/repository classes you should write separate tests for them as well.