# Should unit tests ensure a specific method was called to arrive at the result?

Tags: unit-testing

Given the following class and method:

```
public class CarService
{
    private readonly ICarModelService _cardModelService;

    public TestMe(ICarModelService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public Car Add(string vin)
    {
        var model = _cardModelService.GetByVIN(vin);
        if (model == "Chevy")
            throw new InvalidCarModelException();
        // other logic
    }
}
```

When testing the `Add` method, is it wise to ensure (via [NSubstitute's `Received` function](http://nsubstitute.github.io/)) that the call `_cardModelService.GetByVIN(vin)` was received or should I only test that the exception `InvalidCarModelException` was thrown?

Is this testing too much?

Comment: I think you should test only what needs to be tested and nothing more than that. Because test code is also code and you also need to maintain. If you think your test adds little value, think twice. My 2c.

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests should cover exactly what their name says - exercise the smallest testable part of an application. If you somehow depend on other preconditions, as you know *[Mocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object)* is primarily used in unit testing.

> An object under test may have dependencies on other (complex) objects.
>   To isolate the behavior of the object you want to test you replace the
>   other objects by mocks that simulate the behavior of the real objects.
>   This is useful if the the real objects are impractical to incorporate
>   into the unit test.

In order to avoid duplicates, you can look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25703505/unit-testing-how-should-i-test-this-kind-of-design/25768018#25768018). To be more specific, what you need to focus on is not the `var model`  object.

> to ensure that the call `_cardModelService.GetByVIN(vin)` was received

Is a matter of another testing types, like [System integration testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_integration_testing).
And just unit test your `public Car Add(string vin)` with both positive and negative approach.