# How to write unit tests for this simple application

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

I have an application with a class registered as a message listener that receives messages from a queue, checks it's of the correct class type (in `public void onMessage(Message message)`) and sends it to another class that converts this class to a string and writes the line to a log file (in `public void handleMessage(MessageType m)`). How would you write unit tests for this?

Comment: Unit test in my opinion should be small and concise you should have unit test to verify that a unit works correctly. May be you are asking for an integration test.

Comment: Integration test too? Are you using maven?

Comment: In order to avoid duplicated answers, you can **[see my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26228523/should-unit-tests-ensure-a-specific-method-was-called-to-arrive-at-the-result/26232511#26232511)** about similar question.

Comment: I am using maven. Perhaps I should skip unit tests and do an end to end integration test.

Comment: I would write at least two unit tests. One to verify that the expected exception is thrown if the message is of the wrong type, and one that verifies that the message is passed on to the other class (that I would mock).

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Mockito in combination with JUnit your test could look like this:

```
public void onMessage_Success() throws Excepton {
  // Arrange
  Message message = aMessage().withContent("...").create();
  File mockLogFile = mock(File.class);
  MessageHandler mockMessageHandler = mock(MessageHandler.class);
  when(mockMessageHandler).handleMessage(any(MessageType.class)
      .thenReturn("somePredefinedTestOutput");
  when(mockMessageHandler).getLogFile().thenReturn(mockLogFile);

  MessageListener sut = spy(new MessageListener());
  Whitebox.setInternalState(sut, "messageHanlder", mockMessageHandler);
  // or simply sut.setMessageHandler(mockMessageHandler); if a setter exists

  // Act
  sut.onMessage(message);

  // Assert
  assertThat(mockLogFile, contains("your desired content"));
  verify(sut, times(1)).handleMessage(any(Message.class));
}
```

Note that this is just a simple example how you could test this. There are probably plenty of other ways to test the functionality. The example above showcaeses a typical builder-pattern for the generation of default-messages which accept certain values for testing. Moreover, I have not really clarified the Hamcrest matcher for the `contains` method on the mockLogFile.

As @Keppil also mentioned in his comment, it makes sense to create multiple test-cases which varry slightly in the arrange and assert parts where the bad-cases are tested

---

What I probably didn't explain enough is that `getLogFile()` method (which with high certainty has an other name in your application) of `MessageHandler` should return the reference to the file used by your MessageHandler instance to store the actual log-messages. Therefore, it probably is better to define this mockMessageHandler as `spy(new MessageHandler())` instead of `mock(MessageHandler.class)` although this means that the unit-test is actually an integration test as the interaction of two classes is tested at the same time.

But overall, I hope you got the idea - use mock(Class) to generate default implementations for dependencies your system-under-test (SUT) requires or spy(Instance) if you want to include a real-world object instead of one that only has null-values as return types. You can take influence on the return-value of mocked objects with when(...).thenReturn(...)/.thenThrow(...) or doReturn(...).when(...) in case of void-operations f.e.

If you have dependency-injection into private fields in place you should use `Whitebox.setInternalState(...)` to inject the values into the sut or mock classes if no public or package-private (if you obtain the testing-model of reusing the package structure of the system-under-test classes within your test-classes) setter-methods are available.

Further, `verify(...)` lets you verify that a certain method was invoked while executing the SUT. This is quite handy in this scenario when the actual assertion isn't that trivial.